# How to create a stub for commands-line using rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm testing a gem that makes external calls to the [Youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) binary, in this moment the tests make 2 calls, one to get a video title and other to download a video:

Get the title:

```
def get_title
  title = `#{YT_DL} --get-title #{get_url}`
  title.delete("\n")
end
```

Download the video:

```
def download_video
  system(YT_DL, '-o', file_path, get_url, '--no-progress')
end
```

And this is my tests:

```
describe Youruby do
include FakeFS::SpecHelpers
let(:video) {Youruby::Youtube.new('uaEJvYWc2ag')}
context 'Youtube'do
  describe 'get' do
    it ".video_title" do
      expect(video.get_title).to eq("FFmpeg-slowmotion.1")
    end
  end

  describe 'download' do
    it ".download_video" do
      FakeFS do
        video.download_video
        File.exists? "#{video.get_title}-#{video.get_id}.mp4"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How i make stubs of this calls? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the Excon or VCR gems which will allow you to stub the HTTP requests.

Comment: i'm using youtube-dl [link](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) it's possible to use Excon or VRC to stub his calls?

Comment: Yes.  VCR (https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/1-6-0/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-rspec), for example, has a 'record' mode that allows you to record a query to the live url.  You can then use the recording (a cassette) for subsequent tests.

Comment: I should add that these solutions work at a different level.  Your code thinks that it's sending out live requests.  Excon/VCR are intercepting the calls and returning a response that you can control.  This is not stubbing within your code but at a higher level that allows your code to think that it's interacting with a real url.